# How can I open Siri Shortcuts Intent in app instead going to setting and add it to Siri & Search?

Tags: siri, spotlight, sirishortcuts

I have added Siri Shortcuts in my app. But to make it actual in work i have to go to settings then in my app i have to go Siri and Search, i have to click on plus to add it, then record a phrase and Done. Instead how can I open Siri Shortcut intent in App to record phrase and configure.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by using the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` and `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController` APIs. Check out the documentation!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inuiaddvoiceshortcutbutton
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inuiaddvoiceshortcutviewcontroller